# How to place span over mat-icon in angular 4 and drop down on Click

Tags: css, angular

I think this has an easy solution, but I am not getting what to do as I am a beginner in CSS. Googled many times but nothing helped me.

In the following demo,

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrdqir

I am having Notification icon with a number of notifications that should be displayed over the icon, but I am not able to position it correctly. The number should be displayed on the right top corner of the icon, but it is getting displayed below the icon. How to place it correctly?

One more doubt,
How do I display those notifications when a user clicks the notification icon? Should I use list item for that or any other way. Please help me guys.

Comment: add `position: relative;` to the button, `position: absolute` and `right: 10%` to the span (and remove `left:10%`)

Answer (score 0):

You can user [badges](https://material.angular.io/components/badge/examples) for this like so:

```
<mat-icon matBadge="15" matBadgeColor="warn">home</mat-icon>
```

You need to import `MatBadgeModule` to use this